# Sharing images and classes across Solution with Multiple Projects for .Net Core, WPF and Xamarin

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded-resource, .net-standard

I'm currently working on a solution that has several different means of delivering the "app" to the end users. I'd like to create a WPF application, an Web App and a Android Xamarin app.

I'm trying an approach that has a class library as the common element between these apps, containing all the class objects and methods in one project. I'm assuming a class library in .NET standard would be sufficient.

So, I understand I will be referencing this class library in each of the these app projects. I have already exercised instantiating some class objects in the WPF and .NET core.

This project has brought me to considering if it were possible to have other things that would be common across these apps, like images for the company logo or items we want to display to the user, or sound effects that I'd like to use.

Now, I've read several threads that are similar, some mentioning Resource Files which I haven't used before.

Any thoughts on the subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just create shared project and keep up all common class here, but the assets you need to apply separately to all projects. Why, you need to apply assets separately means, the android assets are various quality and different folders, when you go to web app mean, it will totally different, so you need to maintain separately.

In the class files and helpers, you can write in shared or common folder in shared project and use it in all you WPF, Xamarin, web app projects.